# Ionic variables.scss toolbar background to primary?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

in "variables.scss",

```
// Shared Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
$toolbar-background: 'primary';

// Named Color Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222
);
```

How to use primary for the toolbar background colour? I have tried 'primary' or primary or $primary, or map-get() or color() something as answered here(https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-variable-scss-color-in-scss-file/68813/2), but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the values from `$colors` before they are defined.

If you move your "Shared Variables" to below "Named Color Variables", it should work just fine :)

Like this:

```sass
// Named Color Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
$colors: (
  primary:    #488aff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222
);

// Shared Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
$toolbar-background: map-get($colors, primary);

@debug $toolbar-background; // #488aff
```

Comment: I see. But that order was not decided by me. Why did the developers of Ionic put colours after the shared variables section where common UI values are defined?